# Disconnected you are now offline

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

Every time i login this message appears i cant connect to internet on ubuntu.I tried disabling and reenabling network manager but it didnt worked.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centarino Wireless-N 1000 [ Condor Peak] [8086:0083]
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centario Wireless-N1000 BGN [8086:1325]
```

Comment: please edit your question with more detail

Comment: @DavidCole can u please explain how should i describe you my problem. please i havent use ubuntu before.I am worried because i need to complete my assignments and i am not getting any solution :(

Comment: How do you connect to internet?

Comment: @Pilot6 i have windows 7 installed too along with ubuntu and i often use wifi on my mobile but i cant connect on ubuntu.As soon as i login into my Ubuntu it says "Disconnected You Are Now Offline" please give me possible solution :(

Comment: Now it is a bit more clear. You use Wi-Fi. Now we need to find out what Wi-Fi module do you have. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centarino Wireless-N  1000 [ Condor Peak] [8086:0083]     Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centario Wireless-N1000 BGN [8086:1325]      04:00.0 Ethernet Controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet [1969:2060] (rev c1)

Comment: @Pilot6 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centarino Wireless-N  1000 [ Condor Peak] [8086:0083]     Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centario Wireless-N1000 BGN [8086:1325]      04:00.0 Ethernet Controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet [1969:2060] (rev c1)

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? And what is the output of `uname -r`?

Comment: @user5441403 -edit- the question. Do not use comments to post information,

Comment: @Pilot6  its not working bro and output of uname -r is 3.16.0-45-generic

Comment: Try #2. What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6  i am using ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: Can you connect to internet by wire?

Comment: And also please add this output TO YOUR QUESTION `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: @Pilot6 no as i am using wifi data card its a dongle that comes with wifi

Comment: So you can connect to internet using the dongle?

Comment: @Pilot6 no i cant i am typing all the outputs:( and that grep command which u said right now didnt gave any output :(

Comment: @Pilot6 no output came from this command :( m worried please help pilot

Comment: Is your system 32-bit or 64-bit? `uname -i`?

Comment: @Pilot6 its 32 bit and output is i686

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: @Pilot6  my net is working now thanks but that three commands which you mentioned are not working

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? And if you problem is solved. accept the answer by clicking the check sign at the left.

Comment: @Pilot6 bro that three command are still not working and i cant update any apps it says package of system is broken

Comment: Please ask another question regarding the other issue.

Comment: @Pilot6 pilot so nice of u bro thanks a lot thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `iwlwifi` kernel module is not loaded.

Connect to internet an alternative way and run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

and reboot.

If you can't connect to internet an alternative way, then download these files:

```
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-lts-utopic/linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic_3.16.0-51.69~14.04.1_i386.deb
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-lts-utopic/linux-image-extra-3.16.0-51-generic_3.16.0-51.69~14.04.1_i386.deb
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-lts-utopic/linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic_3.16.0.51.42_i386.deb
```

Copy them to your Ubuntu Home folder and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot.

If your wifi starts working, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You will have the kernel updated. If the wireless still does not work, run:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

and reboot again.

Comment: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-lts-utopic/linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic_3.16.0.51.42_i386.deb   dosen't work!!!!!