# ath10k_pci wifi adapter present, but wireless settings absent and can't connect to any wifi

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, recently I upgraded packages and since then I am facing the issue of no wifi settings and wifi networks are not visible.
[screenshot of wifi settings absent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcL2z.png)

Please help me out, I tried quite a few solutions available but none helped me till now. Here are some outputs of commands. When I run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I get Disconnected - you are now offline.

The output for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k` is

```
3c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Dell Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:076e]
Kernel driver in use: alx
Kernel modules: alx
3d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
3e:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba America Info Systems XG4 NVMe SSD Controller [1179:0115] (rev 01)
```

The output of `sudo rfkill list all` is

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

and that of `uname -r` is

```
4.15.0-118-generic
```

The output of `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
  *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
   logical name: enp60s0
   version: 10
   serial: 18:db:f2:3e:bd:93
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.29.96 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:16 memory:dd500000-dd53ffff ioport:d000(size=128)


*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3d:00.0
       version: 32
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dd200000-dd3fffff
```

Wifi Adapter is also not present in Additional Drivers settings if I wanted to upgrade it.
My laptop is Alienware 13 R3 and as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/765865/929472) the files look complete.
Solutions that I tried and didn't work for me are [one](https://askubuntu.com/a/475579/929472), [two](https://askubuntu.com/a/607982/929472), [three](https://askubuntu.com/a/773598/929472), [four](https://askubuntu.com/a/688102/929472), [five](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028199/929472), [six](https://askubuntu.com/a/661434/929472), [seven](https://askubuntu.com/a/876001/929472).

All the packages are up-to-date. Please suggest some solution to me, I love Ubuntu, I can't use Windows.

---

Edit 1: Output of `dmesg | grep ath` is:

```
[    2.693687] ath: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_channel (err 0)
```

---

Edit 2: Results of

```
$ ls /etc/modprobe.d
alsa-base.conf                  blacklist-rare-network.conf
amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf  blacklist-watchdog.conf
backports.conf                  dkms.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf          fbdev-blacklist.conf
blacklist.conf                  intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf         iwlwifi.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf      mlx4.conf
blacklist-modem.conf            nvidia-396_hybrid.conf
blacklist-oss.conf              nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf

$ sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version
Version: 1.157.23
```

Comment: Please edit to add results from terminal for `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks, I have added, please check.

Comment: Please add the result of: `ls /etc/modprobe.d` and also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version`

Comment: Did you install the backports?

Comment: @chili555 added results.

Comment: @Jeremy31 yes I had referred to this https://askubuntu.com/a/1028199/929472

Comment: Do `cd backport-iwlwifi && sudo make uninstall` then reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 wow, wifi works. thanks a lot for helping me out. Were backports causing an issue? or is it something else?

Comment: Yes the backport-iwlwifi only works for some Intel wifi devices from what I have seen, nothing else will work